# Can't find what I should change from "Undefined offset: 1" PHP notice

Tags: php, arrays, joomla3.0

I've got this error :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/joomla/Joomla_3/modules/mod_menu/helper.php on line 59

I found after searching that it might be due to the first parameter of an array that is not defined. But I tried many things and I can't find what I should change to make this work without the notice.

Here is the helper.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_menu
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Helper for mod_menu
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_menu
 * @since       1.5
 */
class ModMenuHelper
{
    /**
     * Get a list of the menu items.
     *
     * @param  JRegistry   $params  The module options.
     *
     * @return  array
     *
     * @since   1.5
     */
    public static function getList(&$params)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $menu = $app->getMenu();

        // Get active menu item
        $base = self::getBase($params);
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $levels = $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels();
        asort($levels);
        $key = 'menu_items' . $params . implode(',', $levels) . '.' . $base->id;
        $cache = JFactory::getCache('mod_menu', '');
        if (!($items = $cache->get($key)))
        {
            $path    = $base->tree;
            $start   = (int) $params->get('startLevel');
            $end     = (int) $params->get('endLevel');
            $showAll = $params->get('showAllChildren');
            $items   = $menu->getItems('menutype', $params->get('menutype'));

            $lastitem = 0;

            if ($items)
            {
                foreach ($items as $i => $item)
                {
                    if (($start && $start > $item->level)
                        || ($end && $item->level > $end)
                        || (!$showAll && $item->level > 1 && !in_array($item->parent_id, $path))
//THIS IS LINE 59       || ($start > 1 && !in_array($item->tree[$start - 2], $path)))
                    {
                        unset($items[$i]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    $item->deeper     = false;
                    $item->shallower  = false;
                    $item->level_diff = 0;

                    if (isset($items[$lastitem]))
                    {
                        $items[$lastitem]->deeper     = ($item->level > $items[$lastitem]->level);
                        $items[$lastitem]->shallower  = ($item->level < $items[$lastitem]->level);
                        $items[$lastitem]->level_diff = ($items[$lastitem]->level - $item->level);
                    }

                    $item->parent = (boolean) $menu->getItems('parent_id', (int) $item->id, true);

                    $lastitem     = $i;
                    $item->active = false;
                    $item->flink  = $item->link;

                    // Reverted back for CMS version 2.5.6
                    switch ($item->type)
                    {
                        case 'separator':
                        case 'heading':
                            // No further action needed.
                            continue;

                        case 'url':
                            if ((strpos($item->link, 'index.php?') === 0) && (strpos($item->link, 'Itemid=') === false))
                            {
                                // If this is an internal Joomla link, ensure the Itemid is set.
                                $item->flink = $item->link . '&Itemid=' . $item->id;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'alias':
                            // If this is an alias use the item id stored in the parameters to make the link.
                            $item->flink = 'index.php?Itemid=' . $item->params->get('aliasoptions');
                            break;

                        default:
                            $router = JSite::getRouter();
                            if ($router->getMode() == JROUTER_MODE_SEF)
                            {
                                $item->flink = 'index.php?Itemid=' . $item->id;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $item->flink .= '&Itemid=' . $item->id;
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    if (strcasecmp(substr($item->flink, 0, 4), 'http') && (strpos($item->flink, 'index.php?') !== false))
                    {
                        $item->flink = JRoute::_($item->flink, true, $item->params->get('secure'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $item->flink = JRoute::_($item->flink);
                    }

                    // We prevent the double encoding because for some reason the $item is shared for menu modules and we get double encoding
                    // when the cause of that is found the argument should be removed
                    $item->title        = htmlspecialchars($item->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
                    $item->anchor_css   = htmlspecialchars($item->params->get('menu-anchor_css', ''), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
                    $item->anchor_title = htmlspecialchars($item->params->get('menu-anchor_title', ''), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
                    $item->menu_image   = $item->params->get('menu_image', '') ? htmlspecialchars($item->params->get('menu_image', ''), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false) : '';
                }

                if (isset($items[$lastitem]))
                {
                    $items[$lastitem]->deeper     = (($start?$start:1) > $items[$lastitem]->level);
                    $items[$lastitem]->shallower  = (($start?$start:1) < $items[$lastitem]->level);
                    $items[$lastitem]->level_diff = ($items[$lastitem]->level - ($start?$start:1));
                }
            }

            $cache->store($items, $key);
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Get base menu item.
     *
     * @param   JRegistry  $params  The module options.
     *
     * @return   object
     *
     * @since   3.0.2
     */
    public static function getBase(&$params)
    {

        // Get base menu item from parameters
        if ($params->get('base'))
        {
            $base = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getItem($params->get('base'));
        }
        else
        {
            $base = false;
        }

        // Use active menu item if no base found
        if (!$base)
        {
            $base = self::getActive($params);
        }

        return $base;
    }

    /**
     * Get active menu item.
     *
     * @param   JRegistry  $params  The module options.
     *
     * @return  object
     *
     * @since   3.0.2
     */
    public static function getActive(&$params)
    {
        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();

        return $menu->getActive() ? $menu->getActive() : $menu->getDefault();
    }

}
```

Comment: `($start > 1 && !in_array($item->tree[$start - 2], $path)))`  if you really want to use this as a tree, than tree is no array.. it is a node

Comment: it looks like joomla is not connecting to the database correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```html
|| ($start > 1 && !empty($item->tree[$start - 2]) && !in_array($item->tree[$start - 2], $path)))
```

empty() will check for existence and that it isn't empty at the same time.